# why does transform from tfidf vectorizer (sklearn) not work

Tags: scikit-learn, tfidf

I'm transforming a text in tf-idf from sklearn. I made the model:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
corpus = words
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 15)
tf_idf_model = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```

And now I'm making vectors for different sets of words (documents), like:

```
word_set = ['dog', 'cat', 'foo']
v = vectorizer.transform(word_set)
```

But I want just one vector of these words, to compare to other documents. But when I use transform, the shape of v becomes:

```
<3x56492 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I want a vector with shape 1x56492, and not 3x56492.. I'm certainly missing something here. Maybe you guys have some tips?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: word_set should be a list of lists(list of vectors).  try putting [['dog', 'cat', 'foo']]

Comment: @yoav_aaa I did `t = [['dog', 'cat', 'foo']]` and `v = vectorizer.transform(t)` and that gave me AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell it's interpreting your new word_set `word_set = ['dog', 'cat', 'foo']` as three separate documents containing one word each, whereas if you did `word_set = ['dog cat foo']` it would interpret this as a single new document containing those words.

What behavior are you expecting from this function? Is `corpus = words` a list of document strings, or a list of single words? If it's the latter, this is likely not doing what you think it is doing, and you should instead make `corpus` a list of document strings.

Comment: Hm, you are right! Thanks. I made the model with documents like: ['dog cat foo', 'dog boo'.. etc]. When I try to do the transform vectorizer now, it gives me 1x(...) vector. Ultimately, i want to check the similarity of the documents with cosine similarity (and also new documents, that's why I needed transform)